# some css queries not working

Tags: css, typography

I'm currently working on this: 
https://codepen.io/juanor/pen/gxELZN

I am having trouble getting my queries for fonts working correctly for two specific parts. They work fine for the entire project but for these two: p.maininfo and .ejkanji, .ejkana, .ejes.

This is my query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
html {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

I'm using for all the elements rem units, and they seem to work just fine with the query. Can someone tell my why these two are the only ones not working?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you explain which specific element isn't behaving, what you expect the font size to be and what it actually is?

Comment: Elements with p.maininfo and .ejkanji, .ejkana, .ejes, texts in the first white box and the last one. In smaller sizes font is supposed to become bigger to improve legibility, but those stay at the same font. It is like the query wouldn't affect them.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work! as It'll be overridden by already written css styles. this concept is called as specificity. Please have a look on [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). you have written styles on elements like.. body, h1-h6, li, p, etc.. so you need to override the same.
E.g,

```
body{
    font-size: 18px;
}
h1{
   font-size : 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
body {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
h1{
   font-size : 20px;
}
}
```

Comment: Most of those styles are writen with rem so body font-size affect them when changed. However, what I am watching in the browser development tools is that queries are not being applied. Those classes font-size is being determined by regular body font-size, not the query body font-size.

Answer (score -1):

You should not use html as the selector to change type. You can use body. I would suggest revising some of your classes and using web developer tools to make sure they are not being over-written by others.

I looked at your code and noticed that your queries can be improved upon. Look for most-used media queries.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `html` as selector use `*`, something like as follows...

Following code is working...

```css
*{font-size: 60px;}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
* {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hwllo World</h1>
```

Comment: I've done it but it is not working yet... It is as if the query isn't affecting those classes.

Comment: @JuanCamiloOrjuela Plese Check Working Example now... I have edited my answer

Comment: @Dhruvang you can use any selector in css here problem is due to specificity concept.

Comment: but dear, for some PHP files. we are not using html tag. For example, take my above program. For it, `html{font-size:50px;}` will not work....

Comment: It has worked for the p.maininfo, but not for the other classes. What I am watching in the browser development tools is that queries are not being applied. Those classes font-size is being determined by regular body font-size, not the query body font-size.